# Posting a Form (User input) into a widget in the admin panel with Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

So I want to post my Form into the Django Admin panel ( into a widget ).
I have already made & styled out my form in HTML & CSS, I just want to post that info to my database and be able to see it for myself in the admin panel in a widget or so, I just want to post the Form data.

So I was wondering for the best way to do this - ANY SUGGESTIONS?

**I want to: Post the user input to the Django Admin panel widget**

My current form looks like this - (I'm using Bootstrap 4, Django VERSION 2, 1, 1 )

Database:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>

        <div class="col-sm-4">
        <form  method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <select class="custom-select custom-select-lg mb-3" name="typeoflocation" type="text" id="DropdownMenu">
                        <option selected>What type of a location is it?</option>
                        <option value="1">Restaurant</option>
                        <option value="2">Bar</option>
                        <option value="3">Office</option>
                        <option value="4">Hotel</option>
                        <option value="5">Other</option>
                </select>

                <select class="custom-select custom-select-lg mb-3" name="location" type="text" id="DropdownMenu">
                        <option selected>In which city is your location?</option>
                        <option value="1">Melbourne</option>
                        <option value="2">Sydney</option>
                        <option value="3">Canberra</option>
                </select>

                <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" name="nameoftheplace" placeholder="WHAT IS THE NAME OF THE LOCATION?">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" name="url" placeholder="WHAT IS THE WEBSITE URL?">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" name="address" placeholder="WHAT IS THE STREET ADDRESS?">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" name="capacity" placeholder="WHAT IS THE SEATING CAPACITY">
                </div>

                <select class="custom-select custom-select-lg mb-3" name="time" type="text" id="DropdownMenu">
                        <option selected>At what time does dinner service typically start?</option>
                        <option value="1">4:00pm</option>
                        <option value="2">4:30pm</option>
                        <option value="3">5:00pm</option>
                        <option value="4">5:30pm</option>
                        <option value="5">6:00pm</option>
                        <option value="6">6:30pm</option>
                </select>

                <select class="custom-select custom-select-lg mb-3" name="numberofdays" type="text" id="DropdownMenu">
                        <option selected>Which days would you like SideSpacer to operate in your space?</option>
                        <option value="1">7 Days a week</option>
                        <option value="2">Weekdays only</option>
                        <option value="3">Weekends only</option>
                        <option value="4">Monday</option>
                        <option value="5">Tuesday</option>
                        <option value="6">Wednesday</option>
                        <option value="7">Thursday</option>
                        <option value="8">Friday</option>
                        <option value="9">Saturday</option>
                        <option value="10">Sunday</option>
                </select>

                <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" name="name"  placeholder="YOUR FIRST NAME">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" name="lastname" placeholder="YOUR LAST NAME">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" name="phone" placeholder="YOUR PHONE NUMBER">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" name="email" placeholder="YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS">
                </div>

                <select class="custom-select" name="reach" multiple>
                        <option selected>What's the best way to reach you?</option>
                        <option value="1">Phone</option>
                        <option value="2">Text</option>
                        <option value="3">E-mail</option>
                      </select>

                <button name="submit" method="POST" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit" style="margin-top:25px; padding-left:20px; padding-right: 20px;
                padding-top: 12px; padding-bottom:12px; margin-bottom: 20px;" value="OK">Submit a Space</button>

                <p class="text-muted">(Our Hospitality Team will follow up with you directly if they feel<br> your location is a good fit for SideSpacer.)</p>

        </form>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to create [models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/) for your questions & answers so that you can store responses and create a [Django form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/) to handle user input.

There are some pretty solid introductory docs on the Django website. [This particular page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial02/) outlines how to create database entries/structures using models and how to access them from the admin console. If you need to know how to display the form itself, I suggest you research forms in Django.

If you prefer videos and want all the information in one place, [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QVX-etwgvJ8) covers most, if not all of what I've mentioned here.

---

Resources:

- Django:

  - [Models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/)
  - [Forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/)
  - [Tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/) ([Page 2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial02/), database setup)
- [YouTube Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QVX-etwgvJ8)

Comment: Hey, Thank you for your reply. I looked into it and I made some models, but still can't find the dropdown menu replacements for the HTML ones in Django, hope I find it. But yes, you did help me with your answer.

Comment: @MarkoLukić, I think that this [choice fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield) may be what you are looking for.